# pyodbc buildozer android sql.h not found Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyodbc, kivymd, buildozer

I'm currently facing the following problem. I've created a KivyMD Android app that establishes a connection to an SQL Server using a connection string. The libraries I'm using are SQLAlchemy and pyodbc. Everything works fine on my Windows computer.

However, when I run buildozer android -v debug on Ubuntu, I encounter the following error message (see below).

`In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12: src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found #include <sql.h> ^~~~~~~ 1 error generated. error: command '/usr/bin/ccache' failed with exit code 1`

Interestingly, I can locate the SQL.h file when I search in the directory: Ubuntu\usr\include. So, the file does exist.

Here's what I've already tried:

Installed unixodbc-dev.
Created a Buildozer recipe for pyodbc.
Updated setuptools.
Installed gcc and g++.

Many Thanks in advance

Tim